# Using SAX parser to validate an xml file against xml schema offline

Tags: xml, parsing, xsd, sax

How to validate an XML file against an XSD local file without connecting to a server using a SAX parser?
What to add and where?
How to change this code?

```
schema = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI).newSchema(xs);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the question you are asking how to connect a local file as a scheme
Example

```
Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(new ClassPathResource("datTag.xsd").getInputStream());
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
```